# How to call array coded in objective c in javascript or html file

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays

I have an array which has some data of lines where I have to display it in onclick of a button in javascript, so how to call a array which is coded in objective C in javascript or to html file.
The following is my Objective c code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Array"ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"csv"];
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n,"]];
        for (NSString* line in lines) {

                 NSLog(@"%@", line);


                }
                NSLog(@" %d", [lines count]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this library:

http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/

Answer (score 0):

JSON-encode the NSStrings or NSArray (`lines`) you want to use in JavaScript.  [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) is a popular JSON library for Obj-C.  You will end up with an `NSString` that represents your data.

Use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` and use your JSON string there as a parameter to a function call or however else you see fit.

Example:

```
NSString *jsonLines = [lines JSONRepresentation];
NSString *javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJavascriptFunctionThatProcessesLines(%@);", jsonLines];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

Sample JavaScript function:

```
function myJavascriptFunctionThatProcessesLines(lines) {
    for(var line in lines) {
        alert(line); // Or whatever
    }
}
```

[json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

[UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21)